# Realtime database templating using Node, EJS and Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database, ejs

I am new to Node JS and I am in the process of migrating from a client-side chat app to a server-side app. When my app was only client-side, any changes to the database, triggered the data to be loaded again into a div, giving the user real-time data. My problem is that with EJS I lose the real-time functionality. Is there a way to maintain the real-time feature?

app.js

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
const http = require("http");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const express = require("express")
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

firebase.initializeApp({
    <MY-CREDENTIALS>
  });

firebase.database().ref("posts").once("value").then(function(snap) {
  posts = snap.val();
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log("Error: " + err);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/index', {"posts": posts});
});

app.listen(8080);

console.log('Listening on 8080');
```

index.ejs

```
<% Object.keys(posts).forEach(function(key) { %>
      <div class='post'>
        <h4 class='body'><%- posts[key].body %></h4>
      </div>
      <br>
    <% }); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

That sure is possible, but it's quite non-trivial.

You'll need to set up a connection between your server and the client, and then send updates from the server to the client as they arrive. Firebase uses web sockets to do this, so that seems like a logical approach.

But as said: it's pretty involved, and you should really wonder if this is the direction you want to go.

Comment: If I did want to do it this way, how would I do so?

Comment: Sorry, but that is way too big for an answer Stack Overflow. I recommend that you start researching what it means to keep a connection between a client and server open, and work from there.